# Is it possible, with CSS-Grid's `gap` property, to choose for there to be gaps between some column or rows - and not between others?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is it possible, with `gap`, to choose for there to be gaps between some columns or rows and not for others?

Comment: short answer: no but if you share your real use case you will for sure get a lot of way to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific columns or rows. The gap property can only change columns, rows or both. You may instead manipulate elements inside your `grid-cells` to have a specific margin such as

```css
margin-left: 20px;
```

Another method is to create a whole empty row/column although this is discouraged.

```css
grid-template-columns: 1fr 20px 1fr; /* 20px gap between the two columns */
```